# Unable to login to Square Enix for Final fantasy on PSN

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I bought FFXIV from flipkart(http://www.flipkart.com/realm.../p/itmdmnw5gjwy2jzw...), registered my product on PSN using the code which came with it but still can't play the game. All the information provided on the squire-enix site seems to be useless, I've tried everything but can't make this OTP thing work even after installing the software token from play store(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details...). It asks for a registration password which I'm not aware of. My game is already registered as shown in the screenshot below. 
[image]
[image]

I contacted them through the e-mail, their fb page, and they do not care to respond

Comment: When did you try to contact the support?

Comment: number of times, first contacted a week ago

Comment: You've to edit your question, half of the links dont work

Comment: which one is not working? all are working for me.. anyways added the screenshots and removed the links

Comment: flipkart is not working neither google.. and you should delete or edit the first picture because your email and birthday is visible

Comment: those may be issues with geoIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try live chat with their support. I had problems in removing my token because I lost it and I do a live chat with their support and my issue got solved.

Take note of their operating hour and its timezone.

Comment: done.. after I was able to login it asked me to update, which was more than 1 GB, so I thought I'd rather than play it. stupid game!